# selecting existing and non existing joined entity at once

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have a join table looks like this.

```
EXCHANGE_RATE
------------------------------
ID                  BIGINT  PK
SOURCE_CURRENCY_ID  BIGINT  FK
TARGET_CURRENCY_ID  BIGINT  FK
```

Mapped ExchangeRate.java

```java
public class ExchangeRate {

    protected ExchangeRage() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    // for SELECT NEW
    public ExchangeRate(Currency sourceCurrency, Currency targetCurrency) {
        this.sourceCurrency = sourceCurrency;
        this.targetCurrency = targetCurrency;
    }

    @Id private Long id;
    @ManyToOne private Currency sourceCurrency;
    @ManyToOne private Currency targetCurrency;
}
```

How can I list all existing and non existing `ExchangeRate`s for given `sourceCurrency`?

For example,

1. There are three Currencies. A, B, and C.
2. There is already an ExhangeRate from A to B

With following method, if `sourceCurrency` is `A`,

```
public List<ExchangeRate> listExchangeable(Currency sourceCurrency) {
    //
}
```

How can I get following list?

```
ExchangeRate {
    id:             0
    sourceCurrency: A
    targetCurrency: B
},
ExchangeRate {
    id:             NULL
    sourceCurrency: A
    targetCurrency: C
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If it doesn't exist, you must create it - you can't query for it from the database.  Select all Currency objects, and then 'select r.targetCurrency, r from ExchangeRate r, where r.sourceCurrency = :sourceC'.  Then create new ExchangeRates for each Currency not in the results of the second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required Query

```
// get all exchange rates for a source currency
public List<ExchangeRate> listExchangeable(Currency sourceCurrency) {
  Query qry = em.createQuery("select r from ExchangeRate r where 
                                 r.sourceCurrency = :sourceCurrency");
  qry.setParameter("sourceCurrency", sourceCurrency);
  return qry.getResultList();
}
```

for non existing ExchangeRates for given sourceCurrency

```
Query qry = em.createQuery("select r from ExchangeRate r where 
                                 r.sourceCurrency != :sourceCurrency");
```